# Is there a way to use foreach to course through an SQLite database and get and use data by row?

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite

I'm creating a project in winforms which is supposed to imitate a library. User logs in, creates a "book" (really just a collection of controls, or user control, with variables storing information inside), stores its information inside an SQLite database, then the program displays it inside a flowLayoutPanel. My problem was that, now, I need to find a way to display **ALL** "books" of that user inside the flowLayoutPanel whenever its form is loaded since the "books" will just be removed upon restarting the program.

[database table for books](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwgsI.png).
In the table for my books in the database there is a field for the username of the user who created that book. I've thought of using foreach to course through the table using the username as a keyword, get the row of data, and create a "book" using each of those information like so:

```
using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(SqliteDataAccess.loadConnectionString()))
{
    foreach(string username in booksTable)
    {
        bookUserControl createNewBook = new bookUserControl();

        createNewBook.guid = cnn.QuerySingle<String>("SELECT guid FROM booksTable WHERE username = " + username);
        createNewBook.username = username;
        createNewBook.title = cnn.QuerySingle<String>("SELECT title FROM booksTable WHERE username = " + username);
        createNewBook.author = cnn.QuerySingle<String>("SELECT author FROM booksTable WHERE username = " + username);
        createNewBook.date = cnn.QuerySingle<String>("SELECT date FROM booksTable WHERE username = " + username);
        createNewBook.desc = cnn.QuerySingle<String>("SELECT desc FROM booksTable WHERE username = " + username);
        createNewBook.photo = byteToImage(cnn.QuerySingle<byte[]>("SELECT image FROM booksTable WHERE username = " + username);); 
        //image is stored as an array of bytes so I need to convert it from byte[] to Image

        //creates the "book" inside the flowLayoutPanel
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(createNewBook);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't know of a way to use the table as a parameter and most I've seen on the web uses list or something else that just won't fit. Any suggestions on a better way to do this? (if this even works at all)

Comment: You can use a `while()` loop to iterate over a `DbDataReader` - and a `foreach` loop over a `DataTable.Rows` collection, FWIW.

Comment: Answers may depend on which driver you are using. Do you have a favorite / required one?

Comment: A common approach is to use an Object Relational Mapper (ORM), like [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli), to convert between database rows and objects. This lets you write queries like `var books = dbContext.Books.Where(b => b.username == username).ToList()`. This does a single db query, without any need to write SQL by hand. If you have *huge* number of books you might want to use pagination or virtualization of the control.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Dapper you can deserialize directly to `bookUserControl`.

It seems you don't have a list of usernames, you want the whole table, so just use `Query<>`. Consider using `async` code to prevent blocking of your UI.

```cs
using IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(SqliteDataAccess.loadConnectionString());
cnn.Open();

const string query = @"
SELECT
  guid,
  username,
  title,
  author,
  date,
  desc,
  image
FROM booksTable;
";
    var allBooks = cnn.Query<bookUserControl>(query, new {username});
    foreach (var book in allBooks)
        book.photo = byteToImage(book.image);
    //image is stored as an array of bytes so I need to convert it from byte[] to Image

    //creates the "book" inside the flowLayoutPanel
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(book);
}
```

Note the use of proper parameterization, rather than injecting the data.

Comment: Yes, I am using dapper. The code looks good so far. Only problem is that the "booksTable" is an SQLite database table, which I do not know how to access in this case (thus a "does not exist in the current context" error), and that createNewBook.image results in "...does not contain a definition for image and no extension method..." due to the program not recognizing its value and instead as a definition of bookUserControl.

Comment: I see, it wasn't clear I thought you alrady had a list of usernames. Point is you need to define a `byte[] image` property. Might be better to just create a separate DTO type (a class just for transferring data from SQL) then copy the info out of that.

Answer (score 0):

Often we use `while` loop, like this

```
// Connect to Database
using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(SqliteDataAccess.loadConnectionString())) {
  cnn.Open();

  string sql = 
    @"SELECT guid, 
             title,
             author,
             date
             /* Add More Fileds if you want */
        FROM booksTable
       WHERE username = @username";

  // Create a parametrized query
  using (SQLiteCommand q = new SQLiteCommand(sql, cnn)) {
    // don't forget to set query parameter
    q.Parameters.Add("@username", SqliteType.Text).Value = userName;

    // Read cursor record after record while creating bookUserControls
    using (var reader = q.ExecuteReader()) {
      while (reader.Read()) {
        bookUserControl createNewBook = new bookUserControl();

        createNewBook.username = username;

        createNewBook.guid = Convert.ToString(reader[0]);
        createNewBook.title = Convert.ToString(reader[1]);
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `Convert.ToString` why? If it's a `string` then just cast it, otherwise cast it to what it actually is. `Convert.ToString` should never be used.

Comment: @Charlieface: I've put `Convert.ToString()` to be on the safer side of the road; say, `guid` field may appear to be of UniqueIdentifier type.

Comment: Then the property should be declared as `Guid`.